# dividing an array into subarrays

Tags: php, arrays, split, divide

I am trying to split the below array. array_chunk, splice, etc dint give me output as expected. Below is the input array:

```
Array ( [0] => Stephen 
        [1] => stephearce
        [2] => s@gmail.com
        [3] => Stephen
        [4] => stephon 
        [5] => stn@kcl.ac.uk  
        [6] => Stephen 
        [7] => richard.stephens 
        [8] => rins@maneer.ac.uk 
      )
```

I want it as below:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Stephen 
        [1] => stephearce 
        [2] => s@gmail.com
      ) 
Array ( 
        [0] => Stephen  
        [1] => stephon 
        [2] => stn@kcl.ac.uk
      ) 
Array (
        [0] => Stephen
        [1] => richard.stephens
        [2] => rins@maneer.ac.uk
      )
```

Using array_chunk is providing me as below, which i dont want like this:

```
Array (
        [0] => Array (
                       [0] => Stephen 
                       [1] => stephearce 
                       [2] => s@gmail.com 
                     )
        [1] => Array (  
                       [0] => Stephen 
                       [1] => stephon 
                       [2] => stn@kcl.ac.uk
                     )
        [2] => Array ( 
                       [0] => Stephen 
                       [1] => richard.stephens 
                       [2] => rins@maneer.ac.uk
                     )
)
```

Please help !

Comment: use a for loop to access the array values

Comment: Stick with array_chunk and loop through the result

Comment: I have to export the values into csv; and so i need values in arrays itslef.
how can I get it done using for loop?

Comment: What you want is 3 separate arrays? So you need to assign them to 3 separate variables.... seems a bit stupid; why not stick with the nested array that you're getting, which can still easily be looped through

Answer (score 0):

To do what you're asking, you need to know how many entries there are in the array (divided by your chunk size of 3, so that you can list those variables:

```
list($var1, $var2, $var3) = array_chunk($myData, 3);
```

but if you're writing to csv, far easier to simply do:

```
$chunkedData = array_chunk($myData, 3);

foreach($chunkedData as $chunk) {
    fputcsv($myFileHandle, $chunk);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is **[working code](http://codepad.org/5nJqaVFm)**:

```
<?
$arr = Array ( 0 => "Stephen",
        1 => "stephearce",
        2 => "s@gmail.com",
        3 => "Stephen",
        4 => "stephon",
        5 => "stn@kcl.ac.uk",  
        6 => "Stephen",
        7 => "richard.stephens", 
        8 => "rins@maneer.ac.uk",
      );
print_r($arr);
foreach ($arr as $item){
    if ($item == "Stephen"){
    if (isset($newArr)) $output[] = $newArr;
        $newArr = array();
    } 
    $newArr[] = $item; 
}
if (count($newArr) > 0) $output[] = $newArr;
print_r($output);
?>
```

**You have full control in foreach loop** - can do whatever You want with this data